# Symfony 2 - doesn't see entity class

Tags: php, namespaces

I have that declaration in my code:

```
\Page\dashboardBundle\Entity\Cars as Cars;
```

but when I try create new object of class Cars ( new \Cars() ), I get error:

> Attempted to load class "Cars" from the global namespace.
>   Did you forget a "use" statement?

What is the reason of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `new \Cars()`, you're trying to create instance of class `Cars` in **root** namespace. That's because of the backslash before class name.

Just remove blackslash:

```
new Cars();
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I get : The class 'Page\dashboardBundle\Entity\Cars' was not found in the chain configured namespaces cron\UpdateClientListBundle\Entity'   Entity exist in different Bundle than controller class.

Comment: That's means that it works, andit's a step forward. ;-) Now you have a different issue, not related to PHP itself, but now it's about Symfony. Google for that error message or provide information (probably in different question) about how you are trying to use it because the context matters now.

Comment: Ok, the problem's cause was that I forgot declared Doctrine's Entity Manager

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "\" character for load class you say at PHP to load in global core namespace PHP.

You already declared the "Cars" class. You don't need to use the "\" character. Just write `new Cars` and code run correctly and you can instanciate  `\Page\dashboardBundle\Entity\Cars`

Answer (score 0):

1. did you add `use` in front?

   `use \Page\dashboardBundle\Entity\Cars as Cars;`
2. did you try removing **"\"** before Cars call?

   `new Cars;`
3. does the namespace entered match the namespace defined in the class itself?

   Meaning, is the location of Class Cars in `\Page\dashboardBundle\Entity\` and does the class itself contain a namespace `\Page\dashboardBundle\Entity\` ?

Comment: unfortunately 3xYES.